Prove Principle of Mathematical Induction and Principal of Well-ordering are equivalent.
I need some help for verification please.
The principle of mathematical induction:
Suppose $P(n)$ is a proposition depending on $n$ for each natural number $n$, such that $P(1)$ is true, and $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
The Well-ordering principle:
If $A$ is a nonempty set of positive integers, then $A$ contains a smallest member.
I have proved they are equivalent, but I am not sure my proof are correct or not. I have put it on below, and can someone help me to verify? Thanks for your help.
This is my method:
Assume the principle of mathematical induction is true. Let $S$ be a nonempty set of natural number and let $P(n)$ be the proposition: If there exists $m \in S$ where $m \leq n$, then $S$ has a smallest element.
When $n=1$, $P(1)$ is true since $S$ only contains one element.
Assume $P(n)$ is true, then there exists $m \in S$ where $m \leq n+1$ since $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$. If $m \leq n$, then by induction hypothesis $S$ has the smallest element. If $m=n+1$, then either $m$ is the smallest element in $S$, or there exists $m' \in S$ such that $m' < m = n+1$. which is the case that $m'$ is the smallest element in $S$ by induction hypothesis. Then we have proved the well-ordering principle.
Conversely, assume the well-ordering principle is true. Suppose $P(n)$ is a proposition for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P(1)$ is true and $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ for each $n$.
Consider $F =\{m \in \mathbb{N} \,\vert\, P(m) \text{ is false}\}$. Suppose $F$ is a nonempty set, then by well-ordering principle there is a smallest element $m$. Namely, $m \geq 1$ and $P(m)$ is false. But since we assume $P(1)$ implies $P(2)$, $\ldots$, $P(m-1)$ implies $P(m)$ is true, hence it leads to a contradiction. Hence, $F = \emptyset$ and we have proved the principle of mathematical induction.

This equivalence has been discussed here many times. Suggest you search for those previous discussions and see how your proof compares to the ones already posted to this site.

Shouldn't a proof verification question have that tag?  And have the proof verification in the question, not as an answer?

The second half of your proof isn't clear.  Try this:
Consider $F=\{ m \in \Bbb N \mid \lnot P(m) \}$ and assume $F \neq \varnothing$.  Then because $F$ is well ordered, it must have a least element $s$.  We know that $P(1)$ is true, so $1 \notin F$, which means (since $s \in F$) that $s \neq 1$.  Therefore, for some $r$ we have $s=r+1$.
But since $r \lt s$ and $s$ is the least element of $F$, we know that $r \notin F$, which means that $P(r)$ is true.  But by hypothesis we also know that $P(r) \Rightarrow P(r+1)=P(s)$, so $P(s)$ is also true.  But that, in turn, means that $s \notin F$, which is a contradiction.  Thus, our assumption that $F \neq \varnothing$ must be false, so $P(m)$ is true for all $m \in \Bbb N$.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
